# Dynamic data loading on custom List-view with background container

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-widget

I am totally confuse with my image list view.
I want to display 2 video poster and text view in a single row with background container ( check attach image of train)

This is single cell of vertical List view.

[image]

Depending on number of videos i have to display vertical list view but each row contain 2 video poster and text view at side of it video with train Engine image at start or end vice versa of row number.

To achieve this UI i write a custom adaptor in which i manage to display train wagon with related image-view by using relative layout.

but how can i manage on-click listener on particular item (particular video in row) on single row.and how can i add train image at start or end of each row

here is output of my code.
[image]

Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Context context = CustomAdapterExample.this;
    ListView ls2 = new ListView(context);
// clear previous results in the LV
    ls2.setAdapter(null);        
    // populate
    ArrayList<Device> videos = new ArrayList<Device>();
    Device my_video;
        for (int i=0;i<05;i++) {
            my_video = new Device("video link","Video id");
        videos.add(my_video);
        }
    CustomAdapter lvAdapter =  new CustomAdapter(context, videos);
    ls2.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    ls2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You clicked on "+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
     setContentView(ls2);
}
```

And here is adaptor

```
class CustomAdapterView extends LinearLayout {        
public CustomAdapterView(Context context, Device device) 
{
    super( context );   
    //container is a horizontal layer
     setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);
    LinearLayout Mainview = new LinearLayout(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams Cellparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Mainview.setLayoutParams(Cellparams);
    ImageView firstImageContainer = new ImageView(context);
    ImageView trackImage = new ImageView(context);
    ImageView VideoViewContainer = new ImageView(context);
    TextView firsttext= new TextView(context);
    firsttext.setText("Testing of app");
    firsttext.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    firstImageContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wagon); 
    VideoViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video); 
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams firstContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(160, 80);
     layout.setLayoutParams(firstContainerParams);
     trackImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams trackRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(755,5); 
     trackRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams firstImageContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140, 90);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams VideoViewContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70,60); 
     VideoViewContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
     VideoViewContainerParams.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
     layout.addView(firstImageContainer, firstImageContainerParams);
     layout.addView(VideoViewContainer, VideoViewContainerParams);
     layout.addView(trackImage, trackRules);
     ImageView secondImageContainer = new ImageView(context);
    ImageView secondtrackImage = new ImageView(context);
    ImageView secondVideoViewContainer = new ImageView(context);
    secondImageContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wagon); 
    secondVideoViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video); 
    RelativeLayout secondLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(160, 80);
    secondLayout.setLayoutParams(firstContainerParams);
    secondtrackImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.line);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondtrackRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(755,5); 
     trackRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondImageContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140, 90);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secondVideoViewContainerParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70,60); 
    secondVideoViewContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    secondVideoViewContainerParams.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
    secondLayout.addView(secondImageContainer, secondImageContainerParams);
    secondLayout.addView(secondVideoViewContainer, secondVideoViewContainerParams);
    secondLayout.addView(secondtrackImage, secondtrackRules);
     firstContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
     secondImageContainerParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    Mainview.addView(layout,firstContainerParams);
    Mainview.addView(secondLayout,secondContainerParams);
    addView(Mainview);
}
     }
  public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter /*implements OnClickListener*/ {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "BI::CA";
private Context context;
private List<videoData> videolist;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Device> videolist ) { 
    this.context = context;
    this.videolist = videolist;
}
public int getCount() {                        
    return videolist.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {     
    return videolist.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
    Device device = videolist.get(position);
    View v = new CustomAdapterView(this.context, device );  
    return v;
}
}
```

If my implementation is wrong than please suggest me some guidance.
gallery is deprecated in API 17 i can't use it.

Is it possible to crate such Ui by using tableview or grid view??

Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: Upvote for the super cute train :3

Comment: @Ascorbin do you have any suggestion? or is it possible to achieve Such Ui by using tableview or grid view?

Comment: I'm too tired to wrap my head around this atm sorry. As to the OnClickListeners: you can always set an OnClickListener to any Layout/ View within your list item's layout.

Comment: @Ascorbin sorry to disturb you...

Comment: @Ascorbin just one question i don't understand why there is gap between my two wagon image..it should close to each other..when you have free time than can you please take a look at my code.

Comment: Probably has to do with the LayoutoutParams that you set on your layouts. Is there a reason a. to use a RelativeLayout and b. to create that layout programmatically instead of in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figure it to display All contain same as on other device by using Include tag in list view layout.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <include android:id="@+id/train2" layout="@layout/train2" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In train I have this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <include android:id="@+id/boogi1" layout="@layout/boogi" />
    <include android:id="@+id/boogi2" layout="@layout/boogi" />
     <include android:id="@+id/engine" layout="@layout/engine" />
```

And to access each Image-view and textview i used

```
 ImageView v1 = ((ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.train).findViewById(R.id.boogi1).findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
```

Thank you for support.
Just one question is it possible to change view for every row depending on position of row..

Comment: that is the answer me and hardik were trying to tell you.. but well done you solved it...

Comment: we were trying to tell you the same thing like one parent Linear Layout with horizontal orientation and other add children's of it using other layout's... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try Custom Listview,,,
try this  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/.

Comment: i am using custom list view please check my code in main question... i want to know that how can i give on click listener on individual video of single row.

Comment: Have you tried setting an OnClickListener on the layout that that contains the video?

Comment: @Ascorbin Cool by using layout.setonclick i can access but how can i get video id ( video number ) .. i tried   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, 
           "item number 1 - "+videolist.get(location)), 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

Comment: @Ascorbin How can i get video id or item id when i click on item

Comment: When you create the Layout/ View, you can setTag to it, put contents in the tag. In the onClickListener onClick, you get back the View and getTag, then get that information from the tag. Just an idea though.